# .net Web Forms Application Drag and Drop not working

Tags: html, visual-studio-2012, drag-and-drop

When I put the following code in an HTML it works perfectly, but when I add it into my VS2012 web forms application it does not. any ideas?

```
<style type="text/css">
#div1 {width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
</style>
<script>
    function allowDrop(ev) {
        if (event.preventDefault) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            event.returnValue = false;
        }
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        if (event.preventDefault) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            event.returnValue = false;
        }
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
</script>


<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<div id="drag1"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="width:300px; height:300px;background-color:blue;">Test</div>`
```

Comment: This only seems to happen when I am working with the debugger in VS when I upload the code to a site it works perfectly fine